# url when uploading file, images don't upload

Tags: php, pdo, filezilla

> localhost ta code works regularl.I threw my filezilla files.While
>   adding an image, url prints the image name to the database, but does
>   not drop the folder image.why could it be

```
    $uploads_dir='images/homepage_balcony/front_face/';
    @$tmp_name =$_FILES['image']["tmp_name"];
    @$name =$_FILES['image']["name"];
    $benzersizsayi1=rand(20000,32000); 
    $benzersizsayi2=rand(20000,32000); 
    $benzersizsayi3=rand(20000,32000); 
    $benzersizsayi4=rand(20000,32000);                
$benzersizad=$benzersizsayi1.$benzersizsayi2.$benzersizsayi3.$benzersizsayi4;
    $image=substr($uploads_dir, 6).$benzersizad.$name;
    @move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$benzersizad$name");
```

Comment: can you show the code you use ?

Comment: $uploads_dir='images/homepage_balcony/front_face/';
 @$tmp_name =$_FILES['image']["tmp_name"];
 @$name =$_FILES['image']["name"];

 $benzersizsayi1=rand(20000,32000);
 $benzersizsayi2=rand(20000,32000);
 $benzersizsayi3=rand(20000,32000);
 $benzersizsayi4=rand(20000,32000);

 $benzersizad=$benzersizsayi1.$benzersizsayi2.$benzersizsayi3.$benzersizsayi4;

 $image=substr($uploads_dir, 6).$benzersizad.$name;
 @move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$benzersizad$name");

Comment: please edit your post and paste your code into your question to have it properly formatted. it is unreadable in comments

Comment: I made corrections

Comment: it is a very bad practice to use `@` to silent errors. try by removing them to see if there are errors. Then you should check for upload errors (into `$_FILE['image']['error']`) before processing the file

Comment: working on localhost .  does not work after uploading to filezilla . why could it be

Comment: the code works but

Comment: it can be a difference in the configuration of php so you have to do what I said to see what the error is, otherwise you have to guess where the error happens...

Answer (score 0):

Please check your folder permissions of 'images/homepage_balcony/front_face/'. All the folders should have writable permissions.